# I am trying to reset password in parse through email i am not finding correct email id for user and i am using this code

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform

I am using this code for resetting password for the user but their is some difficulty found I am not found correct email address for the user which is I am entered in user `UITextField`.It take any registered email in the parse could.

```
-(IBAction)ForgotPassword:(id)sender
{

   UIAlertView * forgotPassword=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Forgot Password" message:@"Please enter your email id" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];

    forgotPassword.alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [forgotPassword textFieldAtIndex:0].delegate=self;
    [forgotPassword show];

}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{



if(buttonIndex ==1){

    NSLog(@"ok button clicked in forgot password alert view");
    NSString *femailId=[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;

    if ([femailId isEqualToString:@""]) {

        UIAlertView *display;

        display=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email" message:@"Please enter password for resetting password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [display show];

    }else{

            [PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:femailId block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            UIAlertView *display;
            if(succeeded){

                display=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Password email" message:@"Please check your email for resetting the password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

            }else{

                display=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email" message:@"Email doesn't exists in our database" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            }

                [display show];
        }];
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**replace below code**

```
 NSString *aStrMSG=[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    if([StrValue length] > 0)
    {
        if(![self validateEmail:StrValue])
        {
            aStrMSG = @"Please insert valid E-mail address";

            if([aStrMSG length] > 0)
            {
                ShowAlert(aStrMSG);
            }
        }
        else
        {
              //Success email is perfect
        }
    }
```

> **Here Check for correct Email address**

```
- (BOOL) validateEmail: (NSString *) candidate {
    NSString *emailRegex =
    @"(?:[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}"
    @"~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\"
    @"x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-"
    @"z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5"
    @"]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-"
    @"9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21"
    @"-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES[c] %@", emailRegex];

    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

**Perfect Solution**

## Editer answer

> **here i have added code for parse Forgot password: so user have to enter their Email address, and email will sent from parse to This
>   email id.**

```
-(IBAction)btnForgotClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"btnForgotClicked Clicked");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter Email Address"
                                                    message:nil
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex==1)
    {
        NSString *emailaddress = [actionSheet textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        [PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:emailaddress];

        HUDSHOW
        [PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:emailaddress block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
            if (!error)
            {
                HUDHIDE
                ShowAlert(@"email sent Succesfully");
            }
            else
            {
                NSString *errorString = [error userInfo][@"error"];   // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
                ShowAlert(errorString);
                HUDHIDE
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to check particular email address for that  user  which is user entered at sign up time

Comment: means u need help of Parse ?

Comment: i have update my answer, please check and if you find helpful then Upvote it.

Comment: it's display some error like unknown receiver actionsheet   and undeclared HUDHOW

Comment: hi it's take any email address which is stored in parse database i am trying for particular email address which is user email address

Comment: Comment HUDSHOW, its not useful to you.